# Dropzone uploaded images are getting duplicate

Tags: jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

Here I have a dropzone file import area.

```
dropZone = new Dropzone("div#fileUpload", {
    paramName: "file",
    url: "/api/v1/upload/session",
    thumbnailWidth: 100,
    thumbnailHeight: 100,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    clickable: '.triggerUpload',
    maxFilesize: 10,
    timeout: 300000,
    success: function(file, response) {
        //console.log('success: ' + file + ' with: ' + response);
    }
});
```

When I upload files and drag a file, it's getting duplicated. Any reason why is that and I want to stop it. Like this can duplicate number of images.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the duplicate I just disabled the mouse actions like this

```
$("div#fileUpload").on('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave mouseup mousedown', function() {
    return false
});
```

To clear much more, I added a CSS also

```
#fileUpload{
    cursor: no-drop;
}
```